# ExtJs 4 How to change the header's height of Accordion

Tags: header, styles, extjs4, accordion

I want to change the header's height of Accordion, I use a css to set the header's height.

```
#panel1 .x-accordion-hd{ height: 40px;}
```

The height is changed but the content of the panel is covered by the header and when the panel is collapsed the next header will cover part of the previous header. Here is the picture. 
  Any help will be appreciated.

[image: The effect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a container inside your accordion panel and set the padding with in the container

```
items: [{
        title: 'Panel 1',
        items:[{
                xtype:'container',
                padding:'25px 0 0 0',
                html:'panel content'
              }]
        },{
        title:'Panel 2',
        items:[{
                xtype:'container',
                padding:'25px 0 0 0',
                html:'panel content'
              }]
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

that's a good idea, and I also find a another solution in http://ext4all.com/post/how-to-change-the-header-s-height-of-accordion, thank you!